# ¿Cómo mando a llamar la clase de un paquete a otra clase de otro paquete?

Tags: java, clase

Esta es mi ventana donde va la barra de menú:

```
package ventanas;

import java.awt.*;    
import java.awt.event.*;    
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import Menu.Archivos;
import javax.swing.*;

public class VentanaPrincipal extends JFrame {

    public static void MostrarVentanaPrincipal(){
        // Declaración de elementos.
        JFrame ventana;
        JPanel panel_01;
        JMenuBar barraMenu;

        //instancias
        ventana=new JFrame("Proyecto Dragon");
        panel_01=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        barraMenu= new JMenuBar();      

        //propiedades de la ventana principal
        ventana.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        ventana.setBounds(0,0,800,600);
        ventana.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //añadiendo el panel al jframe
        ventana.add(panel_01, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        //añadiendo la barra de menu al panel
        panel_01.add(barraMenu, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);

        //añadiendo el menu archivo a la barra de menu
        Archivos Arv = new Archivos(); 
        barraMenu.add(Arv);

        //mostrando la ventana principal
        ventana.setVisible(true);

}  
}
```

Y esta es mi clase Archivos:

```
package Menu;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Archivos extends JMenu{

private JMenu Archivo;

private JMenuItem nuevo,abrir,guardar,cerrar;

    public Archivos() {

        //instacias
        Archivo=new JMenu("Archivo");
        nuevo=new JMenuItem("Nuevo");
        abrir=new JMenuItem("Abrir");
        guardar=new JMenuItem("Guardar");
        cerrar=new JMenuItem("cerrar");

        //añadiendo los items del menu archivo
        Archivo.add(nuevo);
        Archivo.add(abrir);
        Archivo.add(guardar);
        Archivo.add(cerrar);            

    }
}
```

Al momento que quiero añadir archivo a la barraMenu no sale error, pero al correrlo no muestra nada en la barra del menú.

Comment: Tu clase archivos debe extender de JMenu para que al agregarla tenga los métodos de un JMenu

Answer (score 1):

Asi tal cual, necesitarías un getter que devuelva el `JMenu` que has llamado `Archivo`, ocurre que `Arv` aunque extiende de `JMenu`, NO es el objeto al que le has agregado las opciones de `JMenuItem`; pero vayamos al código...

```
public JMenu getMenu() {
  return Archivo;
}
```

por tanto en la clase principal te faltaría corregir por algo como lo siguiente:

```
Archivos Arv = new Archivos();
barraMenu.add(Arv.getMenu());
```

Porque basicamente `Archivo` es el atributo (componente `swing` en este caso) al que has instanciado y agregado los `JMenuItem`. En ese orden de ideas hasta la clase `Archivos` puede sin ningún problema NO extender de `JMenu`

**Ahora, otro modo alternativo:**

```
Archivos Arv = new Archivos();
barraMenu.add(Arv);
```

para que ese código pueda agregar el menú se debería modificar la clase `Archivos` así:

```
public class Archivos extends JMenu{

//private JMenu Archivo;

private JMenuItem nuevo,abrir,guardar,cerrar;

    public Archivos() {
        //instacias
        //Archivo=new JMenu("Archivo");
        setText("Archivo");
        nuevo=new JMenuItem("Nuevo");
        abrir=new JMenuItem("Abrir");
        guardar=new JMenuItem("Guardar");
        cerrar=new JMenuItem("cerrar");

        //añadiendo los items del menu archivo
        /*Archivo.add(nuevo);
        Archivo.add(abrir);
        Archivo.add(guardar);
        Archivo.add(cerrar);*/
        add(nuevo);
        add(abrir);
        add(guardar);
        add(cerrar);
    }

    /*public JMenu getMenu() {
      return Archivo;
    }*/
}
```

En este caso, no hay por ningún lado algún componente `JMenu` (salvo comentarios), sino que se agregan los `JMenuItem` directamente a la clase que es de tipo `JMenu`.

Después de todo lo anterior obtuve esta captura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]